# Sensitivity analysis in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, sensitivity-analysis

I would like to run a sensitivity analysis of two logistic regression model in order to compare them and make a judgment in for what model a specific IV had an higher impact on the probability.

My question is: What is the appropriate procedure?

I know I can run a simulation on a given regression model, where I keep all IVs constant except the one I wanna examine for its reaction on the regression models (mean) probability.

However, the following question remains unclear to me:

1. What values do I choose to keep constant (group means? group probabilities?) and how do I variate the IV I wanna examine?

Feel free to ask my any questions for further clarification.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is sensitivity testing or measuring significance. If it's the former, why not just look at the sensitivity of changing the independent variable's coefficient on your dependent variable prediction? If it's the latter, you can use packages like relaimpo (assuming you are using R) to determine the relative significance of each variable given different permutations of including independent variables.